# How to include the full source code of angular in a angular-cli project, for exploring the source with intellisense in vscode?

Tags: angular

When using vscode and an angular-cli based project, you can use intellisense to navigate to angular symbols (F12, ctrl-shift-f10, etc).

Out of the box you navigate to the d.ts-files in the distribution of the (angular and other third party) modules in node_modules.

It would very helpful if you could include the full source code of the given version of the angular and other third-party modules you use, and make intellisense open the source. For quick lookup, exploration, learning, etc.

Is it possible to configure your project to achieve this?

I assume this is independent of the use of vscode - the same setup could be used in Sublime Text etc.

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the source maps. Have you tried this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9729#issuecomment-373232983

Comment: This question is not related to sourcemaps of modules in npm_modules - this is not about using the debugger. But sourcemaps of dependencies would also be usefull:)